# Hybrid Application and Applet

Tags: java, html, applet, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

We are working in a HTML5/JS based Hybrid project that requires executing some files on client machine. I was looking into the web and figured out that signed applet may be the way to achieve that.

The application we are building is meant to work offline so we are caching the html and JS files using cachemanifest.mf. Now the question is can we cache the applet related file (basically the jar file) similar way ? When the app gets launched in offline mode  will the applet code will be executed?

Answer (score 1):

The caching and availability of the Jar is not defined for a standard applet (it might be cached, it might not).

However if the applet is deployed (embedded or free floating) using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), we can specify the download of jars as `eager` to ensure they are downloaded before the app. starts, and `offline-allowed` to ensure the applet itself is usable offline.